# WinTV-quadHD randomly stops working

Tags: mythtv, tv-tuner

I'm having trouble with my WinTV-quadHD.  All four tuners work fine, but it seems after using any one of them, they randomly stop getting any signal.  By "randomly" I mean that if I start watching or recording TV again, some tuners work fine, while others show no signal.  Sometimes I can reset it by doing something like `echo 1 >/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/remove && echo 1 >/sys/bus/pci/rescan` and get some or all of the tuners back, but it only works sometimes.  Rebooting usually works, but that is a major inconvenience.

I've checked the mythtv logs and all it tells me is that the tuner failed to get a signal lock in the allotted time (8 seconds).

One other bit that might be relevant is that I usually suspend the computer when it's not in use.

Where else could I check to see any messages related to the PCI device not working right?

xubuntu 20.04 LTS
linux kernel 5.4.0-33-generic
mythtv v31.0